# How to restrict a correlation heatmap to interesting cells and add stars to mark exceptional values?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

I'm trying to do a nice correlation matrix heatmap in python, but I can't find the options to customize it the way I want.

My code is simply this one:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(Correlazioni.corr(), dtype=np.bool))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(Correlazioni.corr(), mask=mask, vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=True, cmap='BrBG')
heatmap.set_title('Triangle Correlation Heatmap', fontdict={'fontsize':18}, pad=16);
```

Now I would like to add (*) in significant cells: ( example: when the coefficient is higher or lower of a certain value)

Thank you very much for the answers, if I missed anything from my request, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: But it's the same result as a pearson correlation? I mean, if the p value is =,003 here will result as a high correlation

How can I display it as significative?

Comment: You seem to be mixing two concepts.     `.corr()` does not calculate P-values.  P-values aren't about correlation, but about [*null hypothesis significance testing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value). So, what's your null hypothesis? How did you calculate the P-values?  What has it to do with [correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)? (Apart from both being named to Pearson.)

Comment: Ok no i'm sorry, my question was only about the correlation index by pearson and spearman. And i would like to mark the cells with high correlation with an (*)

Comment: I did it.. my problem is that I don't know yet how SPSS calculate the level of significance so, I can't give you the exact number above or below .. but i'll work on that, for now It would help know how to integrate the "mark the significant cell" !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show less cells, you can extend the mask, masking away the non-wanted values.
Instead of just setting `annot=True`, also a list of strings can be provided. You fully control how you format these strings, and e.g. append stars:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(124)
Correlazioni = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(7, 10), columns=[*'abcdefghij'])

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
corr = Correlazioni.corr()
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=np.bool))
cut_off = 0.6  # only show cells with abs(correlation) at least this value
extreme_1 = 0.75  # show with a star
extreme_2 = 0.85  # show with a second star
extreme_3 = 0.90  # show with a third star
mask |= np.abs(corr) < cut_off
corr = corr[~mask]  # fill in NaN in the non-desired cells

remove_empty_rows_and_cols = True
if remove_empty_rows_and_cols:
    wanted_cols = np.flatnonzero(np.count_nonzero(~mask, axis=1))
    wanted_rows = np.flatnonzero(np.count_nonzero(~mask, axis=0))
    corr = corr.iloc[wanted_cols, wanted_rows]

annot = [[f"{val:.4f}"
          + ('' if abs(val) < extreme_1 else '\n★')  # add one star if abs(val) >= extreme_1
          + ('' if abs(val) < extreme_2 else '★')  # add an extra star if abs(val) >= extreme_2
          + ('' if abs(val) < extreme_3 else '★')  # add yet an extra star if abs(val) >= extreme_3
          for val in row] for row in corr.to_numpy()]
heatmap = sns.heatmap(corr, vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=annot, fmt='', cmap='BrBG')
heatmap.set_title('Triangle Correlation Heatmap', fontdict={'fontsize': 18}, pad=16)
plt.show()
```

[image: example heatmap]

Here is how it looks like with the empty rows and columns removed. Note that it doesn't look perfectly triangular anymore.

[image: empty rows/columns removed]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you so so so much  @JohanC !!!! : )

Comment: I would like to add one thing though:
-for values between x and y = * 
-for values below y= **

annot = [[f"{val:.2f}" + ('' if abs(val) >= extreme and <=y else '\n★') + (" if abs(val) > y else \'n★★') + (for val in corr[col]] for col in corr]

Is it right?

Comment: Thank you, really!! It's perfect @JohanC