# Why is my correlation matrix displaying a fully white picture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, correlation

I have plotted a correlation matrix using this code:

```
sns.set_theme(style="white")

# Compute the correlation matrix
corr = final_df.T.corr()

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 12))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(230, 20, as_cmap=True)
# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=.3, center=0,
            square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

This is the result:

[image]

I don't understant why is this happening. I have tried another way to do it:

```
corr = df.corr()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 12))
ax.matshow(corr, vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.xticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns, rotation='vertical', fontsize=8);
plt.yticks(range(len(corr.columns)), corr.columns, fontsize=8);
```

But still the result is:

[image]

My data doesn't seem to be bad. Here's what the correlation matrix looks like:

[image]

Can someone explain me why is this happening, and how to fix it please?

Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT**

In response to @mwaskom comment. I have removed the `linewidth = .5` argument and the problem seems to be partially solved. I said partially because some points started to appear in the plot but it is impossible to truelly visualize anything.

This is what i get after removing the `linewidth` argument:

[image]

I have tried with a bigger fig size (36, 24) before it was (24, 12) but it still the same. Here's a screenshot (The screenshot couldn't capture the whole figure)

[image]

Is there any way to get this plot helpful in visualizing the correlations?

**UPDATE**

The result still prety much the same using Arty's answer. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

I've also tried JohanC's suggestion in the comments. This one is nearer to produce meaningful results, but still:

[image]

Any fixes you could suggest please?

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to remove `linewidths=.5`; it looks like your data are too dense to draw even very thin lines between the cells without the lines filling the space.

Comment: Hi @mwaskom thank you for your answer. I tried what you said but it is still impossible to get some useful information from that plot. I have edited the question  to update the results i have now. Would you have any other suggestions to improve the plot visualization please ? Thank you

Comment: If you have too much information to fit in the allotted space, you either need to show less information or make the space bigger. You mention trying to change the figure size, but you don't give enough details to help diagnose why it didn't work.

Comment: @mwaskom i've changed the figure size from (24, 12) to (26, 24). I don't know what more details can i give. Ask me anything you need to know. I have posted a screenshot of the figure with increased size. The size of my data is 1216 × 1216.

Comment: Also see [How to restrict a correlation heatmap to interesting cells and add stars to mark exceptional values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171071/how-to-restrict-a-correlation-heatmap-to-interesting-cells-and-add-stars-to-mark/66175716#66175716) for a way to remove uninteresting rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohanC. I tried your answer in the post you quoted and it's near to produce meaningful results, but it still not good. I have updated the question for you to see what i got using your answer. Maybe you have an idea to make it work properly. Thanks again

Comment: With so many rows, you need `annot=False` (which also gets away with the variables, `extreme_1` etc and the matrix of annotations from that post). And you could set the `cut_off = ` variable to a higher number to cut away more rows/columns.

Comment: Your heatmap is meaningless and looks like gray triangle only because there are very many values. You have about 100x100 of values. To see visually nice results try just plotting heatmap with 10x10 array of values. You'll that everything is correct and nice. You just need to output less values at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just a way to many values to see any meaningful heatmap, because I tried to reproduce your picture with very small array and succeeded. Try to show fewer values at once. Also set `vmin = -1, vmax = 1`. My code is:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66873860#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="white")

# Compute the correlation matrix
corr = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [-0.2, 1, 0], [0.3, 0.7, 1]], dtype = np.float64)

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24, 12))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(230, 20, as_cmap=True)
# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,
            square=True, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
            
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Arty thank you very much for your answer. i tried what you suggested but still i'm getting the same results. I have updated the question to show what i've got

Comment: @Miguel2488 What's wrong with the last image in your question? That one by JohanC. Looks like correct stuff. You have a sparse heatmap. Because you have very many elements you have very tiny squares. In my answer squares are really big because there are just 3x3 values. Try in your case to start from very small array. For example draw your image for 10x10 array. Try using my code in my answer, it is almost same as yours. Just put into my code your 10x10 data. You'll see very meaningful result.