# Marking heatmap with pvalues

Tags: python, r, seaborn, visualization, heatmap

I have a matrix of beta coefficients from a set of regression modesl I ran and the assocaited p-values.  I want to make a heat map of the beta valeus with an asterix or a star in the values that achieved significance.  Preferably two stars one to demarcate a bonferonni threshold and another to demarcate FDR.  How can I annotate values in heatmap.2 with a symbol or otherwise?  I would happily accept a seaborn solution as well.

```
#example of betas
> bees[1:3, 1:3]
                    smri_thick_cdk_banksstslh smri_thick_cdk_cdacatelh smri_thick_cdk_cdmdfrlh
Height                             0.61403585                0.9574614               0.8578689
Weight                             0.07517904                0.6418907               0.2238402
Waist Circumference                0.07336446                0.4155540               0.1593594

#sample of p-values
> peas[1:3, 1:3]
                    smri_thick_cdk_banksstslh smri_thick_cdk_cdacatelh smri_thick_cdk_cdmdfrlh
Height                             0.61403585                0.9574614               0.8578689
Weight                             0.07517904                0.6418907               0.2238402
Waist Circumference                0.07336446                0.4155540               0.1593594

#example heatmap
heatmap.2( x=as.matrix(bees[1:3, 1:3]),
           dendrogram="none",
           keysize = 1,
           key.title = NA,
           key.ylab = NA,
           density.info = "none",
           trace = "none",
           Colv = "Rowv",
           scale = "none",
           main = "betas")
```

[image]

Comment: `heatmap.2` has a `cellnote` option that you can use for that. Possible duplicate, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305232/r-how-to-plot-a-heatmap-that-shows-significant-correlations/66322447.

Comment: See also [How to restrict a correlation heatmap to interesting cells and add stars to mark exceptional values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171071/how-to-restrict-a-correlation-heatmap-to-interesting-cells-and-add-stars-to-mark)